# wordpress comment spamming even no form in website

Tags: wordpress, comments, spam

Hello i have wordpress website i have no comment form in my website on any page

but when i see in admin comment section i see lots of unnecessary comments.

So how people are able to comment on website?

is this from any media image or else i don't know.

how ever i have disabled it from some templates which are used in front end

```
<?php comments_template(); ?>
```

what should i do to prevent it, how ever i have i have recently installed plugin and testing if comment appears or not.

```
http://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-comments/
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to dashboard->Settings->Discussion and uncheck "Allow link notifications from other blogs (pingbacks and trackbacks)"
 
to learn more:
http://www.optiniche.com/blog/117/wordpress-trackback-tutorial/